# When (& where) are my fragments created

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I'm using the viewpagerindicator library (http://viewpagerindicator.com/) to create some sort of wizard for my android app. It works fine and does exactly what I want.

I would like to "extend" the functionality a bit by having "previous"/"next" buttons in my ActionBar - pretty much as in Android's "Done Bar" tutorial - to step through the wizard. Works like a charm, too.

HOWEVER:
I would like to display information about the "next" & "previous" fragment in the ActionBar's buttons. Information I pass to the fragments that live in the ViewPager at the time of their "creation" (actually at the time of their object instantiation - using the classical "newInstance(...)" approach to create the instance of my fragment, store the parameters in a Bundle and extract them in the fragment's "onCreate" method). The same way the template does it, when you create a new fragment for your project.

So, this information is the thing I actually want to display in my wizards button to know what fragment is next and which was last.

The type of this information is not important for my problem. It could be a String or an icon or an int or ... anything else you want.

However, wherever I've tried to access my fragments data, the fragment has not yet been fully initialized (meaning its "onCreate" method has not been called yet).

I've tried it in the host fragment's "onViewCreated" method, because I thought that's where all its subviews should be initialized already (at least their "onCreate" method should have been called, I thought), but it seems that this is handled differently for ViewPager to retain only the number of fragments in memory that was set by setOffscreenPageLimit.

So, what I'm looking for (and probably just missing) is the correct callback method here. One that is called when the ViewPager's next Fragments have been loaded and initialized. If such a callback exists, I could place my little piece of code there to update the text in my "previous"/"next" buttons within the ActionBar.

Any help, comments, ideas are highly appreciated. If needed, I can also try to attach some code sample to better explain my setup, but I think it should be easy enough to understand what my problem is.

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: I also tried to do this by using EventBus to send "onFragmentInitialized" messages from my fragments within in the ViewPager and the hosting fragment. It actually worked, but it does not seems the proper way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a Fragment's onCreate Method is called, its already preparing to be displayed, and practically its past the point where its considered a Next or Previous fragment instead its considered current.

A fragment's onCreateViews method is called after committing a transaction in the FragmentManager. which takes less than 1 sec to bring it in front of the user (depending on the device and runtime environment)

But in your case, your data should be initalized outside the Fragment that uses it, and displayed where ever you want by passing the data itself then displaying whatever you want form it.

decouple your data from android objects (Fragment, Activity ...) and you should be able to load, maintain, access it cleanly and without worrying about their callbacks.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Mr. Me. I select your answer as the "accepted", since I agree that solving the problem by decoupling the model from the view is probably the best way to do it. It's however the old discussion how to properly separate the model from the view on android (not in this special case but in general), so I'd be happy to hear other people's opinion in case there is a more 'android-like' way to do it. Cheers.

Comment: its not only about concepts, android does recycle its objects for so many reasons, so you can't guarantee a relationship between them, that is one more reason to keep your data away from them.

Answer (score 1):

The Fragment's arguments can be read and loaded in its onAttach callback rather than onCreate, the Activity will then (after onAttach is complete) get a onAttachFragment callback with the Fragment as a parameter. However, I doubt onAttachFragment will be called when switching between already loaded pages in the view pager.

If not, you could have the fragment notify the activity (through an interface) that it is now active during its onActivityCreated, onViewCreated or similar method.

But it sounds more like the activity should register as a page changed listener to the ViewPager itself, and update its state depending on the page rather than which fragment is active.

As a side note, ViewPagerIndicator is quite old now (hasn't been updated in 3 years), a more modern approach is the SlidingTabs example from Google, which has been built into a library available here: https://github.com/nispok/slidingtabs

Comment: Thanks for your fast response, FunkTheMonk!

I totally agree on the fact, that the update should actually happen on the registered listener for a page change. As a matter of fact I already have the update there (as well), but this only works when the user actively changes the current page (unless I'm doing something wrong here or misunderstand what you mean), not at the initial startup.

Therefore yes - but does not do the trick at the host fragment's creation (or host's activity creation - in my case the host with the ViewPager is a fragment, but that doesn't make much of a difference).

Comment: The approach with the callback interface is of course a common design pattern for many cases, I agree, but I don't really want the fragments to know that they are within a "wizard" (or any other container). If I would rely on such a callback interface I would kinda couple the fragment to the wizard.

As for your link: thanks for that, too. I'll have a look at it.